# Finding out date format in the list of house numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, convert, date, format

In my dataset, the data which contains house numbers are converted to date format in QGIS. Is there any script or tool to identify and convert them to normal format?

E.g. Case:

Actual Door No format is `11-10-60` and converts to Date format  `11/10/1960`

How can we identify the date format in the list of data and convert it back to the actual door no format?

Comment: To be clear: from a field house number, you want to convert the values to a date format which matches your example., am I right? Do the house numbers have a similar format to this one 'xx-xx-xx' ?

Comment: i want the door number format back (11-10-60)

Comment: I guess its a CSV? Then you could just force QGIS to read this field as string.

Answer (score 10):

If you import from CSV, change data type from `Date` to `Text(string)` when importing CSV.

[image]

Otherwise, add another field using the following expression in Field Calculator (set door number field before using).

```sql
lpad(month(door), 2, '0') || '-' || lpad(day(door), 2, '0') || '-' || right(year(door), 2)
```

[image]